# MongoDB How to get active times of a host using timestamp arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following kind of MongoDB documents in my database:

```
{
    "ts" : [
        ISODate("2015-11-27T18:15:21Z"),
        ISODate("2015-11-27T18:15:22Z"),
        ISODate("2015-11-27T18:15:30Z")
    ],
    "host" : "178.197.235.109",
    "minTs" : ISODate("2015-11-27T18:15:21Z")
},
{
    "ts" : [
        ISODate("2015-11-25T20:12:07Z"),
        ISODate("2015-11-25T20:12:08Z"),
        ISODate("2015-11-25T20:12:11Z")
    ],
    "host" : "178.194.35.159",
    "minTs" : ISODate("2015-11-25T20:12:07Z")
},
```

The timestamps ts describe where a specific host was visible to the system. What I want to know by aggregations and/or projections is in how many sessions the user was active. For this reason I define a session offset of 3s. If any pair of subsequent timestamps of a host differ at most this session offset, I assume these timestamps to belong to the same session. If not, a new session was started. In the first record, we would have 2 sessions, in the second one 1. Note that it's possible that a user was only visible once.

Is it possible to query the number of sessions for each document? I'm quite stuck at the moment and would appreciate any help!

Thanks & Cheers
Simon

Comment: Why in the second `3`? I think in the second also it is `2`.

Comment: you're right, there was an error. but it's actually one single session (08-07 <= 3s, 11-08 <= 3s)